# A simple maths operation on a CSV column using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have this CSV file that I need to plug into an API, but one of the columns is in Dollars, and I want to convert it to cents by multiplying by a 100

Here's the file

```
tripId,scooterId,userId,totalDuration,pickUpTime,dropOffTime,userLocationAtBooking.0,userLocationAtBooking.1,userLocationAtDropOff.0,userLocationAtDropOff.1,totalFare
18721,927,38579,45,2021-08-22 03:00:49,2021-08-22 03:45:39,24.76412,46.6493,24.76409833,46.64934,9.58
18722,434,38563,45,2021-08-22 03:01:16,2021-08-22 03:45:39,24.76412,46.64933333,24.76407,46.64933333,13.53
18723,876,38554,33,2021-08-22 03:05:57,2021-08-22 03:38:55,24.71392833,46.660645,24.7097,46.66272,0.67
18724,476,32291,65,2021-08-22 03:14:37,2021-08-22 04:18:56,24.77137833,46.64568667,24.7722,46.64523167,32.35
```

I only need to do the maths operation on the last column, "totalFare"

I'm still new to python, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm so confused right now. If you multiply dollars with 100, it's still dollars in hundreds.
`Edit`. I get it now. As it is simple math, there are many operations on stackoverflow. Please refer to it.

Comment: Start from reading something about processing csv in python e.g. https://realpython.com/python-csv/ if you don't know from where to start. You haven't shown any try to find solution for your problem.

Comment: well yeah but now its in cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it was still unclear on how to perform the task here's an implementation using basic Python

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as in_file, open('result.csv', 'w') as out_file: # Open input and output files
    out_file.write(next(in_file))                # Reads header from input file and writes to output file
    for line in in_file:                         # For each line in file (we are past header line)
        line = line.rstrip().split(',')          # Create list from comma separated string
        line[-1] = f'{100*float(line[-1]):.0f}'  # Convert last item in list to float and multiply by 100
                                                 # and convert foat to stringto 0 decimal places
            
        #line[-1] = '{:.0f}'.format(100*float(line[-1])) # Alternative to above line that doesn't use
                                                         # f-string (i.e. can use in earlier versions of Python)  
        
        out_file.write(','.join(line) + '\n')    # Output updated list as comma separated string
```

**Output** (using example input)

```
tripId,scooterId,userId,totalDuration,pickUpTime,dropOffTime,userLocationAtBooking.0,userLocationAtBooking.1,userLocationAtDropOff.0,userLocationAtDropOff.1,totalFare
18721,927,38579,45,2021-08-22 03:00:49,2021-08-22 03:45:39,24.76412,46.6493,24.76409833,46.64934,958
18722,434,38563,45,2021-08-22 03:01:16,2021-08-22 03:45:39,24.76412,46.64933333,24.76407,46.64933333,1353
18723,876,38554,33,2021-08-22 03:05:57,2021-08-22 03:38:55,24.71392833,46.660645,24.7097,46.66272,67
18724,476,32291,65,2021-08-22 03:14:37,2021-08-22 04:18:56,24.77137833,46.64568667,24.7722,46.64523167,3235
```

**Alternative using Python Pandas module** (much shorter solution)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')               # Read CSV file into Pandas DataFrame
df['totalFare'] *= 100                     # multiply total_fare by 100
df.to_csv('result.csv', index = False)     # Write to output file as csv
```

Comment: Attempting to parse CSV by hand in python in 2021? That's a good one. You know the `csv` library exists, right?

Comment: @l4mpi --yes I'm familiar with the CSV library and have used it often.  But, the operation is so simple here what would be the point of using it?  Do you see how it would improve on my code?

Comment: First, using DictReader/Writer would simplify your code. Second, your code will simply fail if presented with any nontrivial CSV feature such as quoting or multi-line records. There's literally never a reason not to use a CSV library on CSV data.

Comment: @l4mpi -- your examples go beyond OP's problem case.  OP's file does not use quoting or multiline records.  If it did, then yes, CSV would be the way to go.  Why don't you post an answer showing how using CSV DictReader would be simpler for this particular problem?

Comment: As I said, it does not matter if OPs 4 presented lines of data can be parsed with your method or not, it's simply a big antipattern to attempt to parse CSV by hand (and not validating headers, as well - your code would also fail if the column order changed). As for posting an answer myself, I'm not answering questions where OP doesn't seem to have invested any effort into solving their own problem.

Comment: @l4mpi -- As the Zen of Python say's "Simple is better than complex.".  I believe this is the simplest answer that handles the problem as OP stated it. It's simple because it handles the specified problem, uses the simplest Python building blocks, and doesn't force him/her to learn another module.

Comment: The zen also says things like "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules". Outside of python aphorisms, there's the saying "use the right tools for the job" - the only right tool for parsing CSV is a CSV parser, split is an antipattern which I've seen cause problems even in enterprise apps (e.g. an Ericsson SDN software). I also think getting people to _not_ learn about python modules is _not_ doing them a favour (re aphorisms, teaching to fish...). But it's your answer so you're free to do whatever you want. I for my part am rooting for the roomba anyways.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and wether or not the CSV library should be used I'm not sure as I'm not that experienced but it works and that's all I needed rn Thank you so much and thanks for pointing out that the CSV library should be used too

Comment: @N4VY_B1U3 -- glad to help.  I added another answer that shows how Python Pandas module would make this even simpler, but Pandas is something you may want to pick up after learning more basic Python.